# Unity XR Direct Interactor Attach Point without changing the object orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation, virtual-reality

I am using the latest XR Toolkit. I have a XR Direct Interactor. I would like to know if there is a way when I pick up an object using this can the objet just retain its current orientation?

It seems to always orient it either to some default orientation or the orientation of an Attach gameobject.

I would like it to not change the orientation of the object you are picking up. Just leave it oriented however it currently is and pick it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to try, first uncheck 'Track Rotation'. If that still doesn't work, add an empty object with the desired orientation/position as an offset object under 'Attach Transform'

[image]

Comment: I did the empty game object and with that can orient the grabbed item any way I want. The problem with that is that I don't want to change the rotation of the grabbed object as it is picked up. Thank you for the tip on tracking rotation and position. I will give that a try and see how it works.